# Should the tensioner-tooth position remain constant during manual crank-shaft rotation?

Tags: timing-belt, compression, tensioner, crank

I have a new timing-belt and tensioner installed in a K7m engine(renault/nissan).

Part of the process is to  rotate the engine manually from the crank bolt, to ensure the markings still align as before.

I noticed there is a change in position of the tensioner-tooth i.e. just as I was aboit to put back the covers followed by the crank-pulley.

Is this a sign I have done something wrong?

(I have left the spark-plugs in, for this job)

Comment: Can you post pictures of what you're talking about? I looked at what it takes to time a K7m engine and it doesn't look overly complicated.

Comment: Yes. Here is a pic of the tensioner I installed: https://tempfile.io/en/ryZpyarsqWpr4jO/preview

I set the tensioner's tooth to be opposite the gap and slightly overlapping the right hand side of the edge of the gap(for wear, which seems to be the norm).

When I rotated the crank shaft, as recommended) twice to check for markings on crank and cam gears, I happened to notice the tensioner tooth had moved, even though the nut is still tight.

Comment: I see now that the tooth moves as soon as I put the crank bolt back on to rotate x2.

The locking pin is in and when I reinsert the bolt by hand I need to tighten it with a wrench so I can turn the engine back just a fraction .... enough to loose the  locking pin.

During this tightening the tooth as move over a bit so that it is slightly more tense.

I'm not sure if this is something I should be concerned about but this has not been mentioned to me so far by anyone.

I do need to use a wrench to get the locking pin out because otherwise the bolt will just loosen again.

Answer (score 1):

If you've followed the directions as listed [in this pdf](https://www.tecnicamotors.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/Distribuci%C3%B3n/K7M-Timing-Belt.pdf), you should have no issues. There is nothing there which states the alignment tabs on the tensioner have anything to do with the timing and is not something you need to check.

> - Fit the tension gauge (mot. 1715)
> - Turn the tensioner pulley anti-clockwise
> - Use the special tool (mot. 1135-01)
> - The tension is set when the tension gauge indicates a value of: (160 ± 10 Hz)
> - Tighten the tensioner pulley nut (50 Nm)
> - Turn the engine 2 rotations by hand
> - Check that the locking pin can be inserted and removed (mot. 1489)
> - Fit the tensioning tool (mot. 1501)
> - Use a torque wrench to adjust the timing belt tension (10 Nm)
> - Remove the tensioning tool
> - Check the tension with a tension gauge (mot. 1715)
> - The tension is set when the tension gauge indicates a value of: (160 ± 10 Hz)
> - Repeat the procedure if required

Comment: Thanks for the advice and reference. That will definitely help me.

I will see if I can find rule-of-thumb equivalents for the tension gauge and torque settings.

Comment: What is 'Mot. 1715', btw?

Comment: Ref: "Mot. 1715" - I have no clue. I've never seen anything specific to that, nor how Renault is advising to adjust the timing belt using tension on the belt itself. I just copied it from the pdf and included it here.